# Gitlab + test cases management tool

Tags: testing, gitlab

i'm searching for a tool (test case management)  which could be integrated with Gitlab and would provide similar functionalities as TestLink

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Currently inspecting web to see what´s availble. it will depends on what you are looking for exactly.

As an open source you have :

- Kiwi-TCMS (http://kiwitcms.org/) but youĺl to do some work to get that works

As paying solution :

- PractiTest (https://www.practitest.com/)
- TestRails (https://www.gurock.com/testrail)
- EasyQA (https://geteasyqa.com/)

I´m currently still comparing multiple solution. You will need to search and compare them to see which one fits your needs.

Comment: Any follow up that you'd like to edit into the answer? I'm interested too.

Comment: I would go for practiTest as it provide an easy and well documented API

Answer (score 0):

To complete this list, there is also a bidirectional integration with the GitLab issue tracker in Klaros-Testmanagement (https://www.klaros-testmanagement.com).

Both the free Community Edition and the commercial Enterprise Edition offer full integration with GitLab.

Disclaimer: Being involved in the development, I am biased.

Comment: "Being involved in the development, I am biased." -> so honest :). In that case, choosing that one i would have direct support contact  :))

Answer (score 0):

GitLab itself is starting to include that feature, not for free though.

See [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#define-test-cases-in-gitlab) (November 2020):

> ### Define test cases in GitLab
>
> The first step towards project-level quality management is here!
> This initial release allows users to define and view test cases from
> within GitLab.
>
> Keeping all of your quality management tools in a single DevOps system
> is essential to ensuring a single source of truth and a single place for
> all participants to collaborate and understand context.
>
> Being able to define test-cases from within GitLab is the first step in this vision.
>
> We intend to build upon this foundation with the creation of Test Sessions, an overall quality management dashboard, and the ability to view test histories
> across multiple deployment targets, such as staging and production.
>
> For more information on our vision, and to collaborate with us, please
> see the [Quality Management Category Direction](https://about.gitlab.com/direction/plan/quality_management/).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_6/test_cases.png -- Define test cases in GitLab]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/test_cases/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/233479).